# First by group then identical for every other group member in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` for which I would like to add a column that calculates a random uniform number once by group for the first group member and then copy the result for the rest of the group. Let's look at this example:

```
DT = data.table(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  code = letters[sample(1:26,6)],
  numvar = rnorm(15,0,1)
)

setorder(DT, ID, code)
set.seed(123)
DT[, Z:=runif(.N), by=ID]; DT

    ID code      numvar         Z
 1:  a    h  0.23821292 0.2875775
 2:  a    h -0.73350322 0.7883051
 3:  a    u -1.04889314 0.4089769
 4:  a    u -0.21586539 0.8830174
 5:  b    b  0.54909674 0.9404673
 6:  b    b -0.78438222 0.0455565
 7:  b    b  1.07061054 0.5281055
 8:  b    g  2.52833655 0.8924190
 9:  b    g -0.05568601 0.5514350
10:  b    g -0.08542326 0.4566147
11:  b    x  0.50381245 0.9568333
12:  b    x  0.82553984 0.4533342
13:  b    x -1.08569914 0.6775706
14:  c    s  1.29476325 0.5726334
15:  c    s -0.33491276 0.1029247
```

In the desired outcome the value `0.2875775` for `Z` would be for all `a`, `0.9404673` for all `b` and so on. Ideally, I would like a solution where I don't have to order, which is why I would like to not use something like the `shift`-function. Better still would be to use `ID` and `code` as double-key which probably is no problem once there is a solution for `ID`

What I tried:

```
DT[DT[, .SD[1], by=ID], Z:= runif(.N)]
```

This does not work and would also just get me the value for the first group member.

Any ideas?

By the way: first or last or any group-member in between does not matter. Just one value per group would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
DT[, Z := rep(runif(1), .N), by = ID]

    ID code      numvar         Z
 1:  b    u -0.86960052 0.9436197
 2:  b    g -0.82605044 0.9436197
 3:  b    q  0.57032375 0.9436197
 4:  a    m  0.56402400 0.2311390
 5:  a    b  1.26068851 0.2311390
 6:  c    l  0.33497025 0.5874900
 7:  b    u -0.24415676 0.9436197
 8:  b    g  0.04127355 0.9436197
 9:  b    q -0.21508139 0.9436197
10:  a    m -0.55698196 0.2311390
11:  a    b -0.88621853 0.2311390
12:  c    l -1.78180519 0.5874900
13:  b    u -0.68728262 0.9436197
14:  b    g  1.07801966 0.9436197
15:  b    q  1.11599245 0.9436197
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I was looking for. DT[, Z := rep(runif(1), .N), by = .(ID, code)] work's as well, as suspected.

Answer (score 1):

> What I tried:
>
> ```
> DT[DT[, .SD[1], by=ID], Z:= runif(.N)]
> ```
>
> This does not work and would also just get me the value for the first group member.

You can do:

```
DT[unique(DT[, .(ID)])[, Z := runif(.N)], on=.(ID), Z := i.Z][]

# or 

DT[.(ID = unique(ID), Z = runif(uniqueN(ID))), on=.(ID), Z := i.Z][]
```